# lldb-360.1.65(xcode8.1) disas command with result error

Tags: ios, lldb

I installed Xcode 8.1 today. It includes the lldb with version 360.1.65. when I debug a armv7 binary on iOS 7.1.2 with lldb . It can't auto disas thumb code. This is my result with disas command.

```
(lldb) disas -s 0x709d8 -e 0x709e0
networkd`_mh_execute_header:
0x709d8 <+39384>: b      0xff3aca20
0x709dc <+39388>: .long  0xf64c6940      ; unknown  opcode
```

I test the same code on lldb-350.0.21.9 (Xcode 7.3.1), it's no problem.

```
(lldb) disas -s 0x479d8 -e 0x479e0
networkd`___lldb_unnamed_function192$$networkd:
0x479d8 <+352>: blx    0x57f74                   ; symbol stub for:     xpc_data_get_bytes_ptr
0x479dc <+356>: ldr    r0, [r0, #0x14]
0x479de <+358>: movw   r0, #0xc800
```

Can anyone help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The information about whether code is arm or thumb is carried in the symbol table, and the debugger reads that.  It looks like in the 8.0 example you're disassembling code that isn't in a function (it's in the binary header), so we can't figure out the right architecture to use.  The 7.1 example is in a function that we recognize (though it's name has been stripped...) so we get it right.

As a workaround, you can force the choice by passing `-A thumb` to `disassemble`.

If you also see this when disassembling code in recognized functions, you should file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: When I use -A `thumb` to `disassemble`. The result  is thumb only. It can't process the first arm code(0x..9d8). Is there any way to switch thumb & arm auto in lldb

Comment: No, lldb doesn't have any "hey, this instruction stream is starting to look like arm not thumb" type heuristics.  That might be doable, but there's often data in code in ARM, so it would be tricky to get right all the time.  It is most likely more trouble than it's worth.  And you generally know from symbols so it isn't necessary most of the time.

Comment: It would be interesting to figure out why you are no longer seeing symbols for the binaries you are trying to disassemble.